# Has the user's guide for the UVM-IEEE-2020 framework been published yet?

Tags: system-verilog, standard, verification, uvm

I was able to find the User's guide for the [UVM-1.](https://www.accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/uvm/uvm_users_guide_1.1.pdf)1 and [UVM-1.2](https://www.accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/uvm/uvm_users_guide_1.2.pdf) frameworks, but I haven't been able to find the same document for UVM-IEEE-2020.

There are of course resources posted at the Accellera's site such [tutorials](https://www.accellera.org/resources/videos/uvm-tutorial-2017) and [videos](https://www.accellera.org/resources/videos) that describe some of the main updates. However, our team is looking for a formal user's guide of sorts.

Comment: This question should not be closed for "recommendation".  The question is not looking for a recommendation.  It is looking for how the IEEE named a recent standard and how to locate it from their site, which can be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [IEEE Std 1800.02-2020](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9195920) is available on the IEEE website.  The document is titled:

> IEEE Standard for Universal Verification Methodology Language
> Reference Manual